# React Bootstrap Checkbox in Nav -> NavItem does not rerender on click

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, typescript, react-bootstrap

I have a peculiar problem with using a Nav and NavItem with a Checkbox from React Bootstrap. The thing is that if I click directly on the checkbox and not the NavItem button the checkbox will not re-render correctly but my state has updated.

Example: Given the code below I render the component and click directly on the checkbox. In this case `showMap` will be set to `false` since we set it to `true` in the constructor but the checkbox will still be checked in the html view. If I however click on the NavItem but not directly on the checkbox both the state `showMap` is updated correctly as well as the view.

https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#navs

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { LinkContainer } from 'react-router-bootstrap';
import { Col, Nav, NavItem, Checkbox } from "react-bootstrap";

interface IProps {

}

interface IState {
    showMap: boolean
}

export class Menu extends React.Component<IProps, IState> {
    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            showMap: true
        }
    }

    toggleCheckbox = (event: any) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.setState({ showMap: !this.state.showMap });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Nav bsStyle="tabs" activeKey="1">
                    <LinkContainer to="/test">
                        <NavItem eventKey="1">Test</NavItem>
                    </LinkContainer>
                    <LinkContainer to="/test2">
                        <NavItem eventKey="2">Test2</NavItem>
                    </LinkContainer>
                    <NavItem eventKey="3" onClick={this.toggleCheckbox}><Checkbox name="showMap" inline checked={this.state.showMap} readOnly >
                    Show Map </Checkbox></NavItem>
                </Nav>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

**Update:**

Tried it like this as well, still the same result:

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { LinkContainer } from 'react-router-bootstrap';
import { Navbar, Nav, NavItem, Checkbox } from "react-bootstrap";

interface IProps {

}

interface IState {
    showMap: boolean
}

export class Menu extends React.Component<IProps, IState> {
    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            showMap: true
        }
    }

    toggleCheckbox = (event: any) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.setState({ showMap: !this.state.showMap });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Navbar>
                    <Nav bsStyle="tabs" activeKey="1">
                        <LinkContainer to="/test">
                            <NavItem eventKey="1">Test</NavItem>
                        </LinkContainer>
                        <LinkContainer to="/test2">
                            <NavItem eventKey="2">Test2</NavItem>
                        </LinkContainer>
                        <NavItem eventKey="5" onClick={this.toggleCheckbox}><input type="checkbox" name="showMap"
                            checked={this.state.showMap} readOnly />Show map</NavItem>
                    </Nav>
                   </Navbar>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: It could be because you are not enclosing your Nav and NavItem components within react-bootstraps's [Navbar](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#navbars) component. It might be worth refactoring your code to work with NavBar's onSelect handler.

Comment: Still looking at this, but it looks like a problem with the Checkbox component. I am reviewing this here https://codesandbox.io/s/3r63j11pzm

Comment: @BenSmith Implemented Navbar but still no luck, if I debug the code I can see that the onClick is hit and the checkbox looks good in the view. However after my onClick code has ran it is reset to look like nothing has changed but state is updated.This happens even if i'm running `event.preventDefault();` or not.

Comment: @GarryTaylor Tried with `<input type="checkbox" name="showMap"
                                    checked={this.state.showMap} readOnly />`but it behaves the same.

Comment: I too have played around with @GarryTaylor nice codesandbox example and it does look like an issue with the react-bootstrap library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Created an issue with React Bootstrap here. https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/2876

They did however think it had to do with React so I created an issue with them https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/11539.

The React team however got to the conclusion this was browser native behavior.

If anyone ends up here this is how I fixed it:

```
toggleCheckbox = (event: any) => {
    this.setState({ showMap: !this.state.showMap });
}

const showMapStyle: React.CSSProperties = {
    paddingTop: '15px',
    paddingBottom: '15px',
}

    ...
    </Nav>
    <div onClick={this.toggleCheckbox} role='button' style={showMapStyle}><input type="checkbox" name="showMap"
        checked={this.state.showMap} readOnly />Show map</div>
</Navbar>
```

I also tried with adding a `li` item inside `<Nav>` but then I got this warning:

> React does not recognize the `activeKey` prop on a DOM element. If you
>   intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute,
>   spell it as lowercase `activekey` instead. If you accidentally passed
>   it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element.

https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/2199

```
<li onClick={this.toggleCheckbox} role='button' style={showMapStyle}><input type="checkbox" id="showMap" name="showMap"
    checked={this.state.showMap} readOnly />Show map</li>
```

Comment: What did you end up doing? I'm facing the same exact problem.

Comment: I just put the `li` inside the `NavDropdown` and it's working now.