# Radio button does not update UI in NavItem

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

Bugged code (also below):
https://codesandbox.io/s/4xklz52xkx

The radio button should become checked after clicking on it, but does not. This *only* occurs in a NavItem. Removing the NavItem div makes the radio buttons work again: https://codesandbox.io/s/5x60q3440l

Could be related to this [react bootstrap issue](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/2876), which was never resolved. The SO post for that issue is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47116194/react-bootstrap-checkbox-in-nav-navitem-does-not-rerender-on-click). I have tested the work around in the answer, with no luck either.

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { Nav, NavItem, Radio } from "react-bootstrap";
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";

class Menu extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selected: "one"
    };
  }

  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({ selected: e.target.value });
    console.log(this.state);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Nav bsStyle="tabs">
          <NavItem>
            <Radio
              name="radioGroup"
              checked={this.state.selected === "one"}
              value="one"
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            >
              one
            </Radio>
            <Radio
              name="radioGroup"
              checked={this.state.selected === "two"}
              value="two"
              onChange={this.handleChange}
            >
              two
            </Radio>
          </NavItem>
        </Nav>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const App = () => (
  <Router>
    <Menu />
  </Router>
);

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: `NavItem` is an `<a>` internally, right?

Comment: Right, `<li>` and `<a>`. `<li role="presentation" class=""><a role="button" href="#">...</a></li>`

Comment: have you tried the preventDefault() method when click event on `<a>` element is triggered (as stated in GitHub issue)?

Comment: I did. However removing `preventDefault()` helped in their case. But it wasn't being used here initially.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, adding a non empty `href` to `NavItem` gets it to work. If you change the NavItem to

```
<NavItem href = '#!'>
```

it works fine. As long as you leave `href` empty or use `#` for href, it doesn't work. I named the `href` `#!` assuming you won't name any of your html elements with `!` !!

I presume [this code snippet](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/blob/v0.32.1-docs.0/src/SafeAnchor.js#L46) in react bootstrap is the issue. But I'm not entirely sure. I'll find the root cause and update the answer.

Comment: Wow that was impressive - how did you figure that out? Any idea what SafeAnchor has to do with NavItem? It is used in [NavLink](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/blob/v4-support/src/NavLink.js#L6) and somehow NavLink becomes a child of NavItem, wrapping the radio buttons. So when the radio buttons are pressed, NavLink prevents the default behavior of the radio buttons.

Comment: I went through the code and this (the code snippet in the `SafeAnchor`) kind of looked fishy. You are looking at a different version of `react-bootstrap` code. If you take a look at the link I put in the answer, you can see that `SafeAnchor` is directly used in the `NavItem` element.

Comment: -- "NavLink prevents the default behavior of the radio buttons"
But the radio buttons trigger `onChange` event and not `click` event. Still the question remains as to why the `handleOnChange` is triggered and state is updated but react doesn't re-render.

Answer (score 0):

Try using e.preventDefault() in your handler. Looks like its defaulting to it's original state.

Comment: Tried here: https://codesandbox.io/s/zxxp25q7k3. I believe `preventDefault` is breaking the default behavior of the radio button. I'm looking into react bootstrap source right now.